# MySQL : convert fractonal years to DATETIME

Tags: mysql, date

I have a time stored as Fractional Years, eg. 1994.232424. I need to convert these into SQL datetime.

Trick is that fractional year is computed against different amount of days on leap years.

I appreciate a good example of how to write down an SQL expression that converts this to date, leap year condition included? I need at least seconds since the beginning of year.

A leap year condition (in mssql, though - I need MySQL option) would be (according to http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/8381/leap-year-logics-in-sql-server.aspx)

```
SET @year = 2012
IF (((@year % 4 = 0) AND (@year % 100 != 0)) OR (@year % 400 = 0))
PRINT '1'
ELSE
print '0'
```

Comment: The calculation seems straightforward to me, just multiply the fraction by (365 + isleap).   But I am curious:  *where* and *why* is such a storage format used in the database?

Comment: basically: `if (isleapyear(...)) { days_in_year = 366 } else { days_in_year = 365}; @days = (1994.232424 - (int)1994.232424) * @days_in_year`

Comment: It's some research tradition in particular science. But for database purposes it has to be stored in datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, my idea is to count the number of seconds between the first day of the next year and the first day of the current year:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAKEDATE(1994+1,1)) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAKEDATE(1994,1))
```

Then multiply this number for the fractional part of the given date:

```
SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAKEDATE(1994+1,1)) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAKEDATE(1994,1))) * 0.232424
```

This gives the number of seconds since the beginning of the year. And you can then add this number of seconds to the first day of the year:

```
SELECT
  MAKEDATE(1994,1)
  + INTERVAL (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAKEDATE(1994+1,1))
             - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAKEDATE(1994,1))) * 0.232424 SECOND;
```

This is a generic query:

```
SET @yourdate = 1994.232424;

SELECT
  MAKEDATE(TRUNCATE(@yourdate, 0),1)
  + INTERVAL (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAKEDATE(TRUNCATE(@yourdate, 0)+1,1))
             - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAKEDATE(TRUNCATE(@yourdate, 0),1))) *
             (@yourdate-TRUNCATE(@yourdate, 0)) SECOND;
```

**EDIT**

I wanted to use UNIX_TIMESTAMP because I didn't want to calculate if a year was a leap year or not, I just wanted MySql to calculate it automatically. But there are other options.

The number of seconds in a year is 31536000 + 86400 more if the year is a leap year.

Another idea is to use `MAKEDATE(year, 60)`, to see if the returned date is in March or in February. `MAKEDATE(TRUNCATE(@yourdate, 0),60)=2` will be evaluated to TRUE (=1) on leap years, and to FALSE (=0) otherwise:

```
SELECT
  MAKEDATE(TRUNCATE(@yourdate, 0),1)
  + INTERVAL (31536000 + (MAKEDATE(TRUNCATE(@yourdate, 0),60)=2)*(86400)) *
             (@yourdate-TRUNCATE(@yourdate, 0)) SECOND;
```

But of course you could use your formula:

```
(31536000 + (((@year % 4 = 0) AND (@year % 100 != 0)) OR (@year % 400 = 0))*86400)
```

to calculate the number of seconds of the year, and then multiply this result for the fractional part.

Comment: Many thanks! It worked. Though, for dates less than 1970-01-01 it does not return anything but year (since UNIX_TIMESTAMP is not working below 1970). Maybe you could also suggest how to make it work for all dates?

Comment: @AskarIbragimov you're right UNIX_TIMESTAMP calculates the number of seconds from 1970-01-01, so it won't work for dates less than that, I've updated my answer, i hope it's okay now